# Проблема с подключением aceoledb в visual studio

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Здравствуйте,
необходимо в C# программно получать доступ к базам данных MS Access, которые будут лежать в соответствующей папке

```
using Data.System.OleDB;
```

...

```
 connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=//DataSource");
```

using Data.System.OleDB  дает ошибку 
"Ошибка CS0234  Тип или имя пространства имен "OleDB" не существует в пространстве имен "System.Data" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку)"

Для этого установил 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components с официального сайта MS

Пытаюсь добавить ссылку на файл C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\aceoledb.dll с помощью Проект->Добавить ссылку->Обзор

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Вопросы в следующем:

1) Как исправить ошибку и правильно ли я пытаюсь подключить это пространство имён?

2) Правильно ли я пытаюсь решить свою задачу? 
Мне необходимо, чтобы в папке лежали типовые данные внутри файлов *.mdb, чтобы дальше в программе вытащить их оттуда и обрабатывать и так как приложение должно работать с разными файлами, то вручную их подключать нецелесообразно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с первым вопросом - я создавал консольное приложение и по каким-то причинам из-за этого при добавлении ссылки не было в диспетчере ссылок в меню слева вкладки COM, когда создал проект для WinForms, то именно на этой вкладке оказались все библиотеки и заработали те, которые я не мог подключить для консольного проекта.